# Getting European Date Format SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, datetime

I have a Database set up with a column for `Datetime`.

In my application a have a date selector.

The issue is that the Db uses American Date Format `(MM/DD/YYYY)` where as the app uses European Date Format `(DD/MM/YYYY)`.

Is there a way to set up the column in the database to use European date format?

I don't want to have to convert through the code in the application.

Comment: Depends on **what** database you're using (SQL is just the query language.... many databases use this). But most **serious** databases like SQL Server will store the `DateTime` **NOT** in string format - but in an internal format, which is **independent** of any formatting. So the formatting is really up to you, when you read out the value from the database table

Comment: Hey, I am using SQL Server 2008 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't store a `DateTime` in any string format - it's stored as an 8 byte numerical value, and a `DATETIME` is a `DATETIME` is a `DATETIME`.

The various settings (language, date format) only influence how the `DateTime` is shown to you in SQL Server Management Studio - or how it is parsed when you attempt to convert a string to a `DateTime`.

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

So if you want to see your `DateTime` in US format, use

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), YourDateTimeColumn, 101)
```

and if you need European (British/French/German) format, use

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), YourDateTimeColumn, 103)
```

It's is a commonly accepted "Best Practice" to avoid using dates as string as much as possible - if ever possible, use the *native* SQL Server and .NET  `DATETIME` datatype for sending back and forth dates (which is **independent** of any regional formatting). Try to convert the `DATETIME` to string **only** when you need to show it (preferably only in your UI - not in your database!)

**Update:** if you want to **insert** `DateTime` values, as I said, I would **strongly recommend** to use a **proper** datatype - and not fiddle around with specifically formatted strings.

If you **must** use strings, then by all means use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use DATE if you only need the date portion, and DATETIME2(n) when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the DATETIME datatype if ever possible

Comment: Its not so much about selecting the DateTime, I just need the database to accept the European date format that is is being written from the application, and preferably store this in European formant also in the table.

Comment: @Gek: as I said - SQL Server **doesn't have** any format associated with a `DateTime` - it's just 8 bytes of binary data - the same for "US" and for "European" dates.....

Comment: OK cool, the problem I have is that when am trying to create a new record from the application say I select todays date I get the error 'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.' But if I select March the first, the record is added and it shows the date as 03/01/2014??

Answer (score 0):

About "*YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS for dates and times - note here: this format has dashes (but they can be omitted), and a fixed T as delimiter between the date and time portion of your DATETIME*":
Another option is the usage of the usual space as separator between data and time: YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS or **YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS.SSS**.
But then, again, dashes have to be omitted: as said for the long format, " *note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! YYYY-MM-DD is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!*"
Please note that the time part **needs** the semi-colons!

Converting to DateTime2 is more tolerant, it works with and without dashes, even using European locales.

Comment: Please rephrase/reformat this answer. I tried to edit it in order to make it understandable but unfortunately, I failed.

Answer (score -1):

Dates don't have a "format" - date *representations* have a format.  You should be passing the dates as dates instead of strings to your application, *then* converting to strings in whatever format is appropriate.

Since you don't say what platform your application is in the code may change, but here's a solution in C#:

```
DateTime dt = reader.GetDateTime(dateColumnIndex);
string s = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```